# How establish a download channel with nghttp2? (c/c++) (AVS)

Tags: c++, c, alexa-skills-kit, nghttp2

After I checked the document of AVS migration (https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/migration-guide)

I made a request after ssl connect done, using "nghttp2_submit_request" which will send a HEADER frame.The data like this:

:method: GET

:scheme: https

:path: /v20160207/directives

authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}

And I found this:

if {{access_token}} is invalid, it would response a json-format string :

{"header":{"namespace":"System","name":"Exception","messageId":"83e5e334-5470-43c4-86d7-be5cbc19a4bd"},"payload":{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED_REQUEST_EXCEPTION","description":"Unable to authenticate the request. Please provide a valid authorization token."}}

but if {{access_token}} is valid , it will response a GOAWAY frame.

So . What should I going to do now? Can any one help me out? It would be a great appreciation```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a sad story.... :(

I run the "javaclient" Client with "companionService" to get the {{access_token}}

And I just past the {{access_token}} to my test client. without close the "javaclient"

At this morning, I close it by chance. So it connected.

Then I test the javaclient open with the test client open .... the GOAWAY frame come as expect.

Then I close the javaclient, run the test client, the GOAWAY frame do not come.

It seems a sad story.....

At this situation, AVS seems can not tell the error infomation...

====================================================

I will close this after fully test...

Comment: I have the same issue. My requests work fine in Java via Jetty, but not in nghttp2. Alexa closes the connection for unknown reasons. :-/

Comment: My situation is : one access_token was used by two client at the same time. Just close one client, the other will work normal.